# logstash split message from log4net into two fields

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

We are new to using logstash and are parsing log4net messages. In the message field currently we have a string output as

```
Some random application name - Some random message
```

I tried to use the 
      gsub => ["message", "-", "App Name"] but it just changed the string and not add it as a new field. What is the best way to get the application name as a new field and remove it from the message field?

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about grok{} with this pattern:

```
   %{DATA:app} - %{GREEDYDATA:otherStuff}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you !